# laravel custom classes add alias

Tags: php, class, laravel, alias

So I want to add a alias for custom classes in order to be able to use them in blade:

```
<?php
namespace App\Classes;

class Requirement
{
    public static function Test()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

In `config/app.php` I added a alias like so:

```
...
'Requirement' => App\Classes\Requirement::class
```

Then, I would like to be able to call it in a blade template like

```
{{ Requirement::Test() }}
```

But the alias is not working somehow. I also tried `composer dump-autoload`, but it's still not working.

BTW: Is adding custom classes like that a viable way to implement site-specific logic like retrieving and processing data from a database or is there a better approach?

**Edit 1**

I created `Requirement.php` in `app/Facades` with following content

```
<?php
namespace App\Facades;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Requirement extends Facade{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'Requirement'; }
}
```

added `PageContentProvider.php` in `app/Providers` with the following content

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class PageContentProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('Requirement', function($app){
            return new \App\Classes\Requirement();
        });
    }
}
```

and in `config/app.php` the alias

```
'Requirement'=>App\Facades\Requirement::class
```

as well as the provider

```
App\Providers\PageContentProvider::class
```

but it's still not working.

**Edit 2**

By adding something like

```
exit();
```

or

```
echo "blabla";
```

inside `register()`, nothing changes. Does that indicate that `PageContentProvider` is not even getting loaded?

**Edit 3**

Since the standard `AppServiceProvider` gets loaded, I deleted the coresponding entry of `AppServiceProvider` in `config/app.php`... *and it still worked!* Somehow my changes don't get applied. Does anybody have solution for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem wasn't the code at all:
After realising that changes in `config/app.php` didn't get applied, a simple

```
php artisan config:clear
```

fixed literally every issue I presented in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your composer file:

```
"autoload": {
    //...
    "files" : ["app/classes/Requirement.php"]
},
```

Then add to your alias as you wrote in your config/app.php

Then you will be able to use in your templates:

```
{{ Requirement::test() }}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, not working - I additionally executed dump-autoload but problem remains: Class 'Requirement' not found.

Comment: Also with the alias? I tested with laravel 5.1 and it's working. Try to create a file in the app directory, name it to something, write a simple method in it: function helloWorld() {echo 'hello'} . Add to your autoload files array, then `composer dump-autoload`, call helloWorld() wherever - to check if it's loading files is the problem itself.

Comment: Also try with to `app/Classes/Requirement.php`, it could be casesensitive if you are running linux/unix

Comment: @lamzozo if that wasn't clear: calling helloWorld() worked, but not calling the class

Answer (score 0):

Try this if this works:

In your controller:

```
 $whateveryour_variable = Requirement::Test();
 return view('yourview',compact('whateveryour_variable'));
```

In your View:

```
   {{$whateveryour_variable}}
```

You could fetch the data in your db then store it in a variable then pass that in your view.

Comment: I'd prefer not to do that, since I would have to keep track about what data should be shipped with the view

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with a slash?

```
{{ \Requirement::Test() }}
```

EDIT: grammar

Comment: I did , not working - wouldn't be a solution for me anyways since I don't want any prefix, just plain <code>Requirement::Test()</code>

Answer (score 0):

What you’re looking for is **Façades**.

You create a Façade class that contains a reference to your class’s binding in the service container, and that’s what you use in the `aliases` array in your **config/app.php** file.

Documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades

Comment: I'll try that, thank you - but shouldn't it work with a plain class as well? Just wondering...

Comment: little side note: when I put anything like exit() or echo "blabla" in register() of the Provider, nothing happens - looks like the provider is not getting loaded.

Comment: @VGD You’re still doing it wrong. You don’t add the class to the `aliases` array, you add the name of the _façade_ class, that contains the reference to your class in the service container.

Comment: Either I'm dumb or I don't get what you're trying to say: My facade class which is referencing my facade _is_ called Requirement, just like the normal class. So I _am_ referencing the facade class in the alias.

Comment: btw when you write _app/config.php_ you actually mean _config/app.php_ right?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you needed a class in Blade:

In stead of setting up an alias, you could use the blade `@inject` function at the top of your blade file.

```
@inject('your_class','App\Helpers\SomeNamespace\Yourclass')
```

Then in the blade template:

```
{{$your_class->doSomething()}}
```